# How to create an observable from a Mongoose find

Tags: node.js, mongoose, observable

I'm new to observables, so I have a question as to how I could create an observable from a search in *Moongose* in Node. From something simple like this:

```
let data = await Message.find().exec();
```

That is, I want that when there is a new message in the Message collection, when creating the observable of it, I can subscribe and get the new data. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `changeStreams` to access real-time data changes in a collection.

[changeStreams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)